# iframe content not properly working in safari

Tags: iframe, safari

I'm trying to display an iframe in a html page .The Iframe not working properly on safari.It

Works perfectly on firefox,ie,chrome.

code:

```
<div id="my-div">
<iframe id="my-iframe" scrolling="no" src="http://weather.yahoo.com/"></iframe></div>
<style type="text/css">
#my-div
{
width    : 200px;
height   : 200px;
overflow : hidden;
position : relative;
}

#my-iframe
{
position : absolute;
top      : -300px;
left     : -400px;
width    : 1280px;
height   : 1200px;
}   
</style>
```

any solution?